# is there a way to generate a gdb-readable coredump when running programs compiled with MinGW?

Tags: c, windows, gdb, mingw

I'm trying to debug a Windows program compiled using MinGW's gcc that only ever segfaults when run *outside* of gdb (probably some race condition... lovely.) The problem is, when the program crashes and I'm not running GDB, I can't get a stack trace... I have the option to open up the program in MSVC when it crashes, but MSVC can't read gcc's debugging symbols and so the stack trace it gives me is useless.

Is there a way to get Windows to create a core dump that I can then later open in MinGW's gdb? Alternatively, is there a way to take MSVC's stack trace (which has raw addresses but no symbols) and use gcc to get a human-readable trace?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

windows does not create core files (on linux they are dumped by the kernel iirc)
you can try to attach with gdb with the crash dialog opened but I doubt it will work

if you use msvc instead you can create a minidump debuggable in visualstudio but there is no way to create same dump with gcc

google made a software that you may find useful, but I'm not sure it can produce stuff with gcc

http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/

or you can set drmingw as jit debugger

```
drmingw -i
```

I'm sure it is possible to get something like a backtrace also on mingw, since mingw compiled llvm is able to dump a trace

http://code.google.com/p/backtrace-mingw/

looks like simpler but I've not tested it

compile with -g3 (and if you can -O0)

Comment: backtrace-mingw looks perfect but I can't get it to build on my mingw64 system. there is already an issue on the github export here https://github.com/cloudwu/backtrace-mingw

Comment: Windows may not create core files, but it can generate dump files (both minidump and full dump files. Anybody know of any way to get gdb to read those?