# Printing stack trace in MinGW in Windows

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, callstack

I'm trying to track down why my multi-threaded app crashes.

So I install a handler for unhandled exceptions using SetUnhandledExceptionFilter and then unwind and print stack trace in the handler. It works..sort of.

I have tried many examples from the internet, but I always get something like this:

```
1 - 0x00401ecc - Unknown Function
2 - 0x00401e83 - Unknown Function
3 - 0x004013fa - Unknown Function
4 - 0x7584336a BaseThreadInitThunk
5 - 0x77dc9f72 RtlInitializeExceptionChain
6 - 0x77dc9f45 RtlInitializeExceptionChainPress <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Never the actual place where the error happened.

Can anyone pls give a real working example of printing a stacktrace for an unhandled exception on Windows ? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If it happens on the machine you are using for development:

- use an IDE (Eclipse CDT, Qt creator, etc) and gdb as a debugger,
- turn compiler optimizatons off (`-O0`),
- compile with debug symbols *enabled* (pass the `-ggdb3` flag to the compiler).

If it happens on a client machine then it is a more complicated situation, see:

- [is there a way to generate a gdb-readable coredump when running programs compiled with MinGW?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5814568/341970)
- [Crash reporting for MinGW applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5225579/341970)

Comment: I have the same problem and this didn't help.

Comment: @Tharteon Please explain your problem, maybe we can figure something out.

Comment: well my problem is that i use boost::stacktrace to get the memory locations for the stacktrace and then decode it using addr2line. But addr2line does not recognize the directions. I discarted the following possible problems: I do include debugging info with -g and -ggdb3, im not using any optimization -O0, i dont strip anything in the executable -s, its not a mingw bug (i changed many versions). 

Its also important to note that this WORKED in the past and stopped working after I changed either the mingw version, the cmake or a combination of the two. Ive been dozens of hours on it.

Comment: Also i went back in time to check if the older version of my project does print the stacktrace but it does not work. So it must be something with my environment or something. I've exhausted even chatgpt, probably the next thing for me to do is change version of boost but my guts tell me its not boost.

Comment: I also created a minimum example of stacktrace generation where i only use boost::stacktrace + addr2line and a main where i print stuff and still does not work. And it does not work in both of my computers, which it's almost hilarious. Because in the past worked in both of them but at some point stopped working.

Comment: Ok the problem for me is that Boost has a bug where stacktrace doesnt work with most mingw versions. This is the issue that solved my problem https://github.com/boostorg/stacktrace/issues/133.

Not only i had the same issue that these people had when i tried to print it with windbg, but also it didnt work using addr2line.

Downgrading mingw to version 7.5 solved it for me. 
And sometime in the future, updating boost might solve the problem once the issue gets fixed

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact problem and it got fixed downgrading MinGW to 7.5.
There is an issue with Boost with lastest version of MinGW which makes it impossible to print stacktraces:

- **[updating to the latest gcc-mingw(x64), stacktrace doesn't seem to build anymore](https://github.com/boostorg/stacktrace/issues/133)**

You have to go to a pretty old version which might be uncomfortable.

This is the only solution I found to be able to print stack traces for MinGW.

Comment: Thank you for posting your findings. It can help others. I added the link to the GitHub issue.